# Locations of root theorem confusion

Tags: real-analysis

Theorem: if f is continuous in [a, b] and f(a) < 0, f(b) > 0, then there exists c in [a, b] such that f(c) = 0.

The most popular proof on the website is proof by contradiction. Thus, we have two cases, f(c) < 0 or f(c) > 0.

first, I suppose f(c) > 0. How can I use continuity to prove that there is a contradiction? The following is my attempt.

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ s.t $\forall x: |x - c| < \delta$ we have $|f(x) - f(c)| < \epsilon$ Also, I let S = {x $\in$ [a, b] : f(x) < 0}. Since S is bounded, I got a least upper bound c. Then, how can I proceed?

Comment: you mean $\exists \delta > 0 $ such that when x in [b, b + $\delta$] we have f(x) > 0?

Comment: can you be more specific? do u mean b + $\delta$ is the least upper bound which is a contradiction?

Comment: I misspoke earlier, you want to use continuity to find an interval around c where $f(x)>0$ and contradict your upper bound

Comment: This is an extension of the intermediate value theorem.  Can you take what you know about that and apply it here?

Comment: I must prove this by contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next section we a prove a proposition by contradiction that can be used by the OP.

---

Proposition 1: Let $g:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a function satisfying $g(x) \lt 0$ for $x \lt b$.
If $g$ is continuous at $x = b$ then $g(b) \lt 0$ or $g(b) = 0$.
Proof
To arrive at a contradiction, assume that $g(b) \gt 0$.
Let
$\quad \varepsilon = g(b)$
Since $g$ is continuous at $b$ we can find a $\delta \gt 0$ such that

$\tag 1 \big (\forall x \in [a,b]\big ) \; |x - b| < \delta \text{ implies } |g(x) - g(b)| < \varepsilon$

It follows that we can find a $x_0 \in [a,b)$ such that

$\tag 2 |g(x_0) - g(b)| < \varepsilon = g(b)$

But then $g(x_0) \gt 0$, a contradiction. $\quad \blacksquare$

---

The OP can now prove the following theorem.

Theorem 2: Let $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(a) \lt 0$ and  $f(b) \gt 0$. Then there exists one and only one number $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f(x) \lt 0$ for $x \in [a,c)$ and $f(c) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible proof is to successively halve the interval. In this way we construct two sequences: nondecreasing $(x_n)$ and nonincreasing $(y_n)$ s.t. $x_n\le y_n$ for any $n$ and $f(x_n)$ is of a constant sign, $f(y_n)$ is of constant opposite sign. We prove that $x_n,y_n$ tend to the common limit, which is a zero of $f$.